# NSButton subclass to change button image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I subclassed `NSButton` so that the button image would change when it is clicked. The following code is used for the subclass.

```
#import "MyImageButton2.h"

@interface MyImageButton2 ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSCursor *cursor;

@end

@implementation MyImageButton2

- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)image {

    [super setImage:image];

    if (!self.image) {
        self.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonicon"];
    }
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    self.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonicon2"];
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    [super mouseUp:theEvent];

    self.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonicon"];
}

- (void)resetCursorRects {

    NSCursor *cursor = (self.cursor) ? self.cursor : [NSCursor pointingHandCursor];

    if (cursor) {
        [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:cursor];
    } else {
        [super resetCursorRects];
    }
}

@end
```

And here is the current button.  As you can see, the button does not return to its original image after it is clicked, the `mouseUp` event.

[image]

Any ideas on why the image is not returned to its original state during the `mouseUp` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to subclass `NSButton` to accomplish this. It can be easily done in your XIB file. In the Interface Builder property inspector, select your button and set the `Type` to `Momentary Change` and then enter `buttonicon` under `Image` and `buttonicon2` under `Alternate`.